# Does anybody know the anime name of 6 girls, who go and fight I believe alien monsters?

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

It's not "Glitter Force", but another anime similar to it. I don't remember much of it, but I remember these girls got sent to another world where there be a jungle and such, and they would be in all different colors, but I cam only remember a blue girl with a sniper rifle, and another girl who was introduced down the story line, and she had a giant mechanical robot who was red.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: When you say " a blue girl", do you mean that she had blue skin or a blue outfit or a blue robot mech suit or what? Who were they fighting againt?

Answer (score 3):

That’s [Yuuki Yuuna is a Hero](https://www.crunchyroll.com/yuki-yuna-is-a-hero) (Yuuki Yuuna wa Yuusha de Aru)

I don’t recall a robot but they fight in a forest and the sniper girl dresses in blue.

[image: Forestize Warning]
[image: pre-transformation]
[image: post-transformation]
[image: sniper]